# Help with script for running AceGen generated routine in ABAQUS

Tags: finite-element-method, scripting, acegen

I am using the below configuration to run a AceGen-generated viscoelastic element in Abaqus.
Abaqus version: ABAQUS 6.14-6,
OS: Windows 10,
Visual studio: 2013,
Fortan compiler: Intel Fortran compiler 2017.
I have downloaded the three script files (given in the template) required for ABAQUS environment and modified them. I have added them into my ABAQUS working directory. Below is a screenshot of the folder
[image]

The path to my intel Fortran compiler is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.187\windows\bin.
The path to my folder with the UEL and input file is:
C:\Temp.
In the ‘ABAQUSCompile.bat’ file, the path of files mentioned in front of  ‘call ifort’ command has 3 parts and, the target files reached by this path aren’t clear to me. Hence, I have left them as is as shown below
[image]

I have modified the ‘abaqus_v6.env’ file as per the instructions given in the manual. My screenshot of the modifications that I have made are as shown below:
[image]

I have left rest of the file as is since I was not able to determine if modifications are required for ‘compile_fmu’, ‘compile_fortran’ and ‘link_sl’. Please find the screenshot of the remaining unchanged part below:

[image]

When I try to run this, I get the below error shown in the screenshot. Is there anything further that needs to be changed? I would be glad to have your help

[image]
In order to check that the compiler is linked correctly, I ran another UEL that was hand-coded. So it is likely that there is an error in how the above is linked. I would be glad to have your help.

Comment: This, to me, does not seem like a question about Mathematica nor the Wolfram Language. You may need to consult somewhere that specializes in the ABAQUS software.

Comment: Did you run ABAQUS through SMSFEEnvironment command? Doesn't look like, since there are some unevaluated parts in your abaqus_v6.env file.